# How do I define a Json Schema containing definitions, in code

Tags: json, f#, jsonschema

I am attempting to replicate the following `Json Schema` example, by defining the schema in code using `Newtonsoft.Json.Schema`:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",

  "definitions": {
    "address": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "street_address": { "type": "string" },
        "city":           { "type": "string" },
        "state":          { "type": "string" }
      },
      "required": ["street_address", "city", "state"]
    }
  },

  "type": "object",

  "properties": {
    "billing_address": { "$ref": "#/definitions/address" },
    "shipping_address": { "$ref": "#/definitions/address" }
  }
```

This is as close as I've got so far.  (Example is in F# but might just as well be in C#.)

Code:

```
open Newtonsoft.Json.Schema
open Newtonsoft.Json.Linq

let makeSchema = 
    let addressSchema = JSchema()
    addressSchema.Properties.Add("street_address", JSchema(Type = Nullable(JSchemaType.String)))
    addressSchema.Properties.Add("city", JSchema(Type = Nullable(JSchemaType.String)))
    addressSchema.Properties.Add("state", JSchema(Type = Nullable(JSchemaType.String)))
    addressSchema.Required.Add "street_address"
    addressSchema.Required.Add "city"
    addressSchema.Required.Add "state"

    let schema = JSchema()
    schema.Properties.Add("billing_address", addressSchema)
    schema.Properties.Add("shipping_address", addressSchema)
    schema
```

Output:

```
{
  "properties": {
    "billing_address": {
      "properties": {
        "street_address": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "city": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "state": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "street_address",
        "city",
        "state"
      ]
    },
    "shipping_address": {
      "$ref": "#/properties/billing_address"
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see, only one of the two addresses is defined using a reference to another schema, and the address schema is in "properties" rather than "definitions".  What's the trick to defining a schema in "definitions" and referencing it elsewhere?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Hackfest! :-)

According to the [source code](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json.Schema/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json.Schema/Infrastructure/JSchemaWriter.cs#L232), JSON.NET Schema just doesn't write a `definitions` property, end of story. So it's all hopeless... Almost.

It does *use* the `definitions` property in another place, however. Namely - [when generating schema from a type](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json.Schema/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json.Schema/Generation/JSchemaGeneratorInternal.cs#L40). During that process, it creates a `JObject`, pushes all schemas into it, and then adds that object to `JSchema.ExtensionData` under the `definitions` key. And when referencing a schema from another place, the schema writer will respect that `definitions` object, if present, thus making the whole thing work together.

So, armed with this knowledge, we can hack our way into it:

```
let makeSchema = 
    let addressSchema = JSchema()
    ...

    let definitions = JObject() :> JToken
    definitions.["address"] <- addressSchema |> JSchema.op_Implicit

    let schema = JSchema()
    schema.ExtensionData.["definitions"] <- definitions
    schema.Properties.Add("billing_address", addressSchema)
    schema.Properties.Add("shipping_address", addressSchema)
    schema
```

And voila! The resulting schema now has a `definitions` object, just as the sacred texts tell us it should:

```
{
  "definitions": {
    "address": {
      "properties": {
        "street_address": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "city": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "state": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "street_address",
        "city",
        "state"
      ]
    }
  },
  "properties": {
    "billing_address": {
      "$ref": "#/definitions/address"
    },
    "shipping_address": {
      "$ref": "#/definitions/address"
    }
  }
}
```

**A few notes:**

1. The `definitions` name is not special from the JSON.NET's point of view. If you change the line `schema.ExtensionData.["definitions"]` to something different, say `schema.ExtensionData.["xyz"]`, it will still work, with references all pointing to `"#/xyz/address"`.
2. <strike>This whole mechanism, obviously, is a hack</strike> Apparently not, [according to James Netwon-King](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json.Schema/issues/60#issuecomment-259569244). The key insight seems to be that the `JsonSchemaWriter` will be able to lookup any previous mentions of schemas and use references to them in other places. This allows one to shove schemas wherever one likes and expect them to be referenced.
3. That `op_Implicit` call in there is necessary. `JSchema` is not a subtype of `JToken`, so you can't just jam it into `definitions.["address"]` like that, you have to convert it to `JToken` first. Fortunately, there is an [implicit cast operator](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json.Schema/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json.Schema/JSchema.cs#L392) defined for that. Unfortunately, it's not straightforward, there seems to be some magic going on. This [happens transparently in C#](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json.Schema/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json.Schema/Generation/JSchemaGeneratorInternal.cs#L76) (because, you know, there is not enough confusion as it is), but in F# you have to call it explicitly.

Comment: Thankyou so much!  We were close to this but op_Implicit was what pushed us over the line.  I've logged an issue: https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json.Schema/issues/60.  Will mark as answer when I've tested this.  (I'm sure it's fine. ;- )

Comment: Used this approach in our "real world" code and it worked like a charm.  Thanks again!

Comment: Glad to be of help